# Avoid powered-off PCs communication at 10Mbit/s thus slowing down broadcasts?

Tags: ethernet, network-adapter, power-management, switch, wake-on-lan

After power failure some PCs enable their network adapters at 10 Mbit/s while powered down.

Those PCs seem to cause network issues if broadcast traffic volume exceeds 10 Mbit/s. This broadcast traffic is intentional and cannot be currently reduced to "normal" volume.

There is neither a jumper that can disable LAN power nor a BIOS-setting that has any effect on this behavior. Updating BIOS has no effect.

Powering such PC on and off seems to resolve the issue by following OS configuration to shut down the network port, but issues reappear after mains power cycle.

The offending computers do need to receive the broadcasts when they are powered on.

They are connected to unmanaged 1000 Mb/s ethernet switches, but I am also interested in a solution involving a managed switch.

The switch seems to wait for broadcasts to complete at 10 MBits/s causing secondary problemns. Those are outside of the scope of this question. I'd like help in resolving this root issue instead.

As a temporary workaround offending PCs are disconnected from mains until they are required, but this cumbersome to enforce.

Is there a known solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: Are you sure there's no BIOS setting? Have you tried disabling Wake-on-LAN?

Comment: It was not enabled in the first place. Enabling or disabling it seems to make no difference.

Comment: Just thinking of a reason why the network adapters would be powered up.  If it's just bad design of the adapter, I'm not sure there's anything you can do except replace the adapters.

Comment: On a managed switch, you could disable broadcast traffic on those ports. But then those PCs can't use DHCP.

Comment: so in what way is it causing issues? are they sending source-quench messages or somthing?  how does this manifest to you (what made you notice it, and investigate to the point you have) and how did you diagnose it? what is the OS in use? have you checked your power options to make sure it won't poweron or wakeon LAN at the OS level?

Comment: Unfortunately receiving the broadcasts is required on the PCs when they are on. The adapters are built into motherboards. Adding network cards is of course a solution, but I'd like to avoid that. I'd like help on resolving this root issue rather than the issues caused by it - those warrant another question. OS is irrelevant - PCs do that even without OS. I haven't encountered the issue after OS boot+OS shutdown, but issue reemerges after power cycling PC - before OS boot. OS is not configured for wake-on-LAN. Resetting BIOS config does not help. RTC battery is ok.

Comment: This sounds very specific to the switch model you're using; I believe most "bigger" switches have per-port queues that would avoid this problem?

Comment: In short this 10Mbit/s connection causes issues on the network switch when it has to broadcast high volumes of data because it has to broadcast to those ports at 10 Mbit/s - which don't need broadcasts when PCs are off - which probably causes queue memory overruns - but that is outside of the scope of *this* question. Assume that reducing broadcast traffic is impossible. Replacing the switch does not seem to help but I only have 2 models with enough ports. My goal here is to somehow get rid of the 10Mbit/s connection entirely or to "remove" broadcasts from powered-off PCs